# How can i solve image upload Error

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I am get successful massage after import,  Check with backend there is no images. 
Magento Version : 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a file/folder permission issue.

Make sure you have all magento patches installed Also if you're able to ssh into your server and navigate to the root of magento and check that the media/wysiwyg/ folder has the right permissions it should have drwxr-xrwx which is 755

```
cd [magento_root]/media
ls -la
```

If folder permissions do not match then run

```
chmod 755 wysiwyg
```

It would also be worth navigating into the wysiwyg folder and then doing an ls -la and checking the file permissions they should be -rwxrwxrwx which is 644

If they are not 644 you can run the following to update them all

```
chmod 644 wysiwyg/*
```

Comment: I did what you said, but still error

Comment: Do you have anything in the system.log or exception.log that could help us debug the issue?

Comment: yes, i am post all my log error in chat @  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42424/what-is-the-suggested-value-of-max-execution-time-and-memory-limit-for-20-000-pro

Comment: yes, i am post all my log error in chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42424/what-is-the-suggested-value-of-max-execution-time-and-memory-limit-for-20-000-pro